# I have 2 wire going into R, how should i connect to nest?

Tags: nest

I'm installing a Nest thermostat:

[image]

How do i connect the blue and red wire? Nest tech said i have two transformer.. do i split them into RH, and Rc?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the indoor unit (air handler) for your system? What do you have for heat for that matter? (A furnace? A boiler? Neither? Both?)